# approximating the density of the studentized range distribution

Tags: density-function, approximation, tukey-hsd-test

Is anyone aware of an approximation to the density function for the studentized range distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentized_range_distribution ? I've found a fast approximation for quantiles made in excel https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/60540520/RapidCalculationOfQ.pdf
And I've found Fortran code for the CDF and another function in the jStat library for cdf values; however I'm curious if there are any coarse approximations for the pdf that are out there - this is to assist in fast plotting of the density curve- it's just a visualization and doesn't need to be too precise.

I appreciate any suggestions anyone has. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347300  Of course, you can always numerically differentiate the CDF.

Comment: Thanks - Looks like some straight forward algorithms for approximating the cdf and the inverse cdf.

Comment: But nothing to give an approximate density function unfortunately.

Comment: I don't follow--if you have an accurate computation of the CDF, you're good to go.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I can try to adapt the code - I'll dig into it and see if I can find a speedy algorithm; The goal is to create something in javascript that can generate an approximate density curve in a few milliseconds. I guess the thing to do is to just calculate F(x) and F(x+delta) and say f(x)=[F(x+delta)-F(x)]/delta

Comment: Because this is a single, fixed distribution for each sample size (approaching a limiting distribution with large sample sizes), you can employ a slow but accurate algorithm to tabulate the values for a suitable collection of sample sizes and then just interpolate in the table: that shouldn't require more than a few *microseconds* or less.